# lighttpd adding vhost error

Tags: lighttpd, virtualhost

I'm trying to have multiple domains.
Followed the instructions from web and added the lines in lighttpd.conf file:

> $HTTP["host"] =~ “(^|.)example.com$” { 
>   server.document-root = “/var/www/example.com″ }

but when I restart the server I get the error:

> (configfile.c.859) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 37 pos:
>   13 invalid character in variable name  2012-02-15 07:38:57:
>   (configfile.c.915) configfile parser failed at: =~

Everywhere I see there characters =~ and I don't know why it won't parse them now.
I'm using Debian 6

Comment: Is line 37 that line?  And is that copied directly from the config file?

Comment: yes this is 37 line from the conf, directly copied. before that I copied from the website. it was quotations, look answer below

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing some non-standard quotation marks (open-quote, close-quote, and something else) in what you've posted, and I think this is what lighttpd is barfing on:

`$HTTP["host"] =~ “(^|.)example.com$” { server.document-root = “/var/www/example.com″ }`

Try instead:

`$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|.)example.com$" { server.document-root = "/var/www/example.com" }`

Comment: man, you have a good eye, congratulations. I didn't even know there was different types of quotations.

Comment: Yup - avoid Word and Wordpad when working with plain-text configs - they'll mangle `-` characters too.